Unit fractions summing to 1 - proving upper bound for the denominators.
Suppose $a_1 < a_2 < \dots < a_n$ are positive integers such that
$$1 = \frac{1}{a_1} + \frac{1}{a_2} + \dotsm + \frac{1}{a_n}.$$
Then $a_n \leq u_n$, with $u_n$ defined by $u_1 = 1, u_{i+1} = u_i(u_i+1)$.
This was proven by Curtiss in [1]; and in [2], the authors claim to have a much simpler proof of this fact. They introduce the following lemma (slightly paraphrased):

Lemma 1. Let $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$ be $n$ real numbers satisfying the conditions
\begin{align}
&x_1 \geq x_2 \geq \dots \geq x_n \geq 0\\
&x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_n = 1\tag{1}\\
&x_1 x_2 \cdots  x_k \leq x_{k+1} + x_{k+2} + \dots + x_n\quad (k=1,2,\dots,n-1).
\end{align}
Then $x_n \geq \frac{1}{u_n}$.

They then say that it is obvious that $x_i = 1/a_i$ satisfy the conditions (1). Well, I seem to be missing something obvious...
In particular, I'm having trouble with proving the third condition holds. Taking $x_i = 1/a_i$ and using the second condition, we can rewrite it as
\begin{equation}\prod_{i=1}^k\frac{1}{a_i} \leq 1 - \sum_{i=1}^{k} \frac{1}{a_i}\quad (k = 1,2,\dots,n-1)\tag{2}.\end{equation}
The case $k=1$ is easy enough. If $n = 1$ there is nothing to prove, and if $n>1$ then (2) is equivalent to $a_1 \geq 2$. Using that
$$\frac{1}{a_1} = 1 - \sum_{i=2}^n \frac{1}{a_i} < 1,$$
we get $a_1 > 1$, and $a_1$ being an integer then means that indeed $a_1 \geq 2$.
The general case eludes me, however. I've tried using induction either side of the inequality, with no success:
$$\prod_{i=1}^{k+1} \frac{1}{a_i} = \frac{1}{a_{k+1} }\prod_{i=1}^{k} \frac{1}{a_i} \leq \frac{1}{a_{k+1}} \left[ 1 - \sum_{i=1}^{k} \frac{1}{a_i} \right] \overset{???}{\leq} 1 - \sum_{i=1}^{k+1} \frac{1}{a_i},$$
and
$$1 - \sum_{i=1}^{k+1} \frac{1}{a_i} = 1 - \sum_{i=1}^{k} \frac{1}{a_i} - \frac{1}{a_{k+1}} \geq \prod_{i=1}^{k} \frac{1}{a_i} - \frac{1}{a_{k+1}} \overset{???}{\geq}  \prod_{i=1}^{k+1} \frac{1}{a_i}.$$
I don't really see where to go from this, or if there's another way to tackle this problem. Any hints would be much appreciated.

[1] Curtiss, D. R., On Kellogg’s diophantine problem., American M. S. Bull. 28, 159 (1922); American Math. Monthly 29, 380-387 (1922). ZBL48.0157.02.
[2] Izhboldin, O.; Kurliandchik, L., Unit fractions, Ladyzhenskaya, O. A. (ed.), Proceedings of the St. Petersburg Mathematical Society. Vol. III. Transl. ed. by A. B. Sosinsky. Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society. Transl., Ser. 2, Am. Math. Soc. 166, 193-200 (1995). ZBL0874.11036.

For any $\;k=1,2,\ldots,n-1\;$ it results that
$\dfrac1{a_1}+\dfrac1{a_2}+\ldots+\dfrac1{a_k}<1\quad$ from which we get that
$\left(\prod\limits_{i=1}^ka_i\right)\!\left(\dfrac1{a_1}+\dfrac1{a_2}+\ldots+\dfrac1{a_k}\right)<\prod\limits_{i=1}^ka_i\;.$
Since the results of the expressions in both sides of the previous inequality are integers, it follows that
$\left(\prod\limits_{i=1}^ka_i\right)\!\left(\dfrac1{a_1}+\dfrac1{a_2}+\ldots+\dfrac1{a_k}\right)\leqslant-1+\prod\limits_{i=1}^ka_i$
and, by dividing both sides by $\,\prod\limits_{i=1}^ka_i\,,\;$ we get that
$\dfrac1{a_1}+\dfrac1{a_2}+\ldots+\dfrac1{a_k}\leqslant-\prod\limits_{i=1}^k\dfrac1{a_i}+1\quad$ hence ,
$\prod\limits_{i=1}^k\dfrac1{a_i}\leqslant1-\dfrac1{a_1}-\dfrac1{a_2}-\ldots-\dfrac1{a_k}\quad$ that is
$\prod\limits_{i=1}^k\dfrac1{a_i}\leqslant\dfrac1{a_{k+1}}+\dfrac1{a_{k+2}}+\ldots+\dfrac1{a_n}$

As is often the case, the critical result is that two distinct integers differ by at least 1.
